# Maven plugin in Eclipse dependency search fails

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I've got a new project with Maven architecture. When I'm trying to add a dependency to my project, m2e finds no jars to match my requests (search result is always empty). 
[image]

My Eclipse settings allow to Download Artifact Sources. (Preferences->Maven)
The Maven repositiry has settings.xml (the default one). What's more, it has some jars inside, but still Eclipse doesn't see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. Settings.xml must look like this.

```
  <mirrors>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>jdk-1.4</id>
      <activation>
        <jdk>1.4</jdk>
      </activation>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>jdk14</id>
          <name>Repository for JDK 1.4 builds</name>
          <url>http://www.myhost.com/maven/jdk14</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <snapshotPolicy>always</snapshotPolicy>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>home</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>Repo for maven</name>
          <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>home</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
```

For m2e to work correctly the Window-Preferences-Maven-Update indexes on startup must be true. Or update maven repository through Show View-Maven Repositories-Global-Rebuild Index

Answer (score 0):

m2e plugin has many bugs. so I recomend you to use official [maven repository](http://search.maven.org) site and add dependency by copy-past into your pom.xml

**And if you want to use m2e plugin check preferencies. May be you need to add some repositories**

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Window → Show View → Other → Maven/Maven Repositories*. Click "OK".
Go to *Maven Repositories → Global Repositories/central*, right click and choose *Rebuild Index* from the context menu. It takes some time to rebuild.